# How to insert multiple captions for multiple images present in word? For example "Figure:1" below image

Tags: vba

I am able to add multiple images to a word document using VBA, but I am not able to add captions for multiple images loaded from folder path.
Can you please suggest on this:

```
Sub checking()
    Dim strFolderPath
    strFolderPath = "C:\images"
    Dim objWord
    Dim objDoc
    Dim objSelection
    Dim objShapes
    Dim objFSO
    Dim objFolder

    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
    Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("D:\myfile.docx")

    objWord.Visible = True

    Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

    For Each Img In objFolder.Files
        ImgPath = Img.Path
        objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture (ImgPath)
        objSelection.InsertBreak
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please edit your question and describe, how the captions should be, e. g. file name of each picture as text below it or headline above it?

Comment: Captions should be inserted in the below of the each imaged loaded in to the word document in VBA. The code shows the loading of all images but not adding the file name of each below it.

Comment: Where is your code embedded, in Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By this you get following order:
- the picture with a paragraph sign
- the image path with a paragraph sign
- a page break

```
For Each img In objFolder.Files
    imgpath = img.Path
    objSelection.InlineShapes.AddPicture (imgpath)
    objSelection.InsertParagraphAfter
    objSelection.InsertAfter imgpath
    objSelection.InsertParagraphAfter
    objSelection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    objSelection.InsertBreak
Next
```

---

Additionally I suggest to use `Option Explicit` at the beginning of each module, which forces a declaration of every variable (e. g. `Dim ImgPath as String`).

Comment: Thanks for update and its working. When I am trying to provide crossreference to each Inserted caption with vba, caption is not reflecting as hyperlinks. so that it can prepare the list of figures as index.

Comment: Fine, then please consider to mark it as answer as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Image name as a hyper link is not visible in the doc.

Comment: I think that your initial question is answered, but you've got a new code-problem now, so please consider asking a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)